# Why does russian peasant multiplication work?

Tags: proof-techniques, mathematical-analysis

can someone provide a proof with induction on why the Russian peasant multiplication work ?

if you don't know  what that is , here is the algorithm :

```
                    P(2·a,⌊b/2⌋)   : b>1 and b is even number
P(a,b):=            P(2·a,⌊b/2⌋)+a : b>1 and b is odd number 
                    a              :b=1
```

Comment: If P(a,b)=a*b then P(2*a,b/2)=(2*a)*(b/2) = a*b (assuming b is even : (b/2)*2=b). You can prove the equivalences, then, iteratively dividing b will converge towards 1, so  the suite will eventually converge to a*b.

Comment: i was able to prove it assuming b is even , but the problem is when b is odd or b-1 it doesn't not equal .

Comment: Please don't repost the exact same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ a \cdot b = p \cdot q + r $.

What's the base case for the induction? $p = a, q = b, r = 0$.

Inductive step: $ a \cdot b = p \cdot q + r$ holds, then $ a \cdot b = p' \cdot q' + r' $ in the next iteration.

**Case 1:** $p$ is odd.
If $p$ is odd, then $p' = \frac{p-1}{2}, q' = 2q, r' = r + q$

$$ p' \cdot q' + r' = \frac{p - 1}{2} \cdot 2q + r + q = pq - q + q + r = pq + r = a \cdot b$$

**Case 2:** $p$ is even. Then $p' = \frac{p}{2}, q' = 2q, r' = r$

That also implies $p' \cdot q' + r' = p \cdot q + r = a\cdot b$

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).

Comment: Also, the OP posted the exact same question before.

Comment: @Raphael can you please explain why  r′=r+q , why exactly +q

Comment: You should look at your recursion.